# Items Page navigation error in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

I have added a new "Items Page" in my win8 app project to display images with description. In the design view, I am able to see all the items with the images but when I debug and navigate to the page, the page breaks. Can somebody tell me the solution?

Comment: What does it mean *the page breaks*? Is there any exception?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka No exception is shown, the apps just crashed on navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (any try of using frame.navigation resulted in crash). Creating new project with the same content(!) helped...